# Plugin and excerpt that doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

This is my code:

```
/*
Plugin Name: myplugin
*/



function my_facebook_tags() {
  echo "testme";
  $myExcerpt = strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); 
  echo "Excerpt ".$myExcerpt;
  echo "Excerpt ".get_the_excerpt();
  echo "Content ".the_content();
  echo "Title ".the_title();
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_facebook_tags' );
```

It prints this:

```
testmeExcerpt Excerpt Content POSTITLETitle
```

Instead of:

```
testmeExcerpt Thisisthecontent Excerpt Thisisthecontent Content Thisisthecontent Title POSTTITLE
```

Why ?

Comment: You are not hooking it inside the loop, and no particular post is selected there, so it does not know or have data for excerpt or content or title... change your hood from wp_head to the_post and see if you get the desired data...

Comment: I see you are trying to output the tags in the head section for Facebook? Try this approach global $post;
echo $post->post_title;

Comment: Thanks, this works for post_title and post_content but not for post_excerpt. Why ?

Comment: You are welcome! Codex mentions that in this context excerpt only is present if it is set manually https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post , i suggest you use post_content and trim using substr php function of any length you want to use.

Comment: Thanks, how could I set the excerpt manually ?

Comment: Excerpts for posts can be set manually here: "To add an excerpt to a post, simply write one in the Excerpt field under the post edit box." https://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt#How_to_add_excerpts_to_posts*

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code.

```
/*
Plugin Name: myplugin
*/



function my_facebook_tags() {
    global $post;
  echo "<br />testme";
  $myExcerpt = strip_tags($post->post_content); 
  echo "<br />Excerpt ".$myExcerpt;
  echo "<br />Excerpt ".$post->post_content;
  echo "<br />Content ".$post->post_content;
  echo "<br />Title ".$post->post_title;
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_facebook_tags' );
```

Please try and let me know.